# MySQL JOIN 3 tables orderby date

Tags: mysql, join

Hey i want to join 3 tables for example

```
TopicID | TopicDate | TopicWroteBy | TopicMsg

TopicID | PostDate | PostID | PostWroteBy | PostMsg

TopicID | PostID | VoteUp | VoteDown | VoteDate | VoteWho | VoteWhom
```

I want to join them all and order by date, (after join they might have some empty cells) although they got much more attributes, but each of them got it own Date.

```
SELECT {0} FROM (topics t LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWho AND t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWhom) LEFT OUTER JOIN reply r ON t.TopicWroteBy = r.PostWroteBy WHERE t.TopicWroteBy = "@USERIDHERE" ORDER BY t.TopicDate DES
```

Here is the code im trying to do it with. It gets now all by the attribute TopicWroteBy and merges some cells i don't want to be merged, although i can't order it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this will answer your question, but I rewrote your query deleting an error at the end (the word is DESC, and not "DES").

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics t LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     votes v ON t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWho AND t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWhom LEFT OUTER JOIN
      reply r ON t.TopicWroteBy = r.PostWroteBy 
WHERE t.TopicWroteBy = 2 ORDER BY t.TopicDate DESC
```

Let us know if you have a more specific issue with ordering. (e.g. nulls first, etc)

#### Edit:

Here is an option. I haven't tested it but maybe you can get the idea. The thing is that you will have to choose which date is more "important" and goes first in the case statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM topics t LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     votes v ON t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWho AND t.TopicWroteBy = v.VoteWhom LEFT OUTER JOIN
      reply r ON t.TopicWroteBy = r.PostWroteBy 
WHERE t.TopicWroteBy = 2 
ORDER BY 
case when t.TopicDate is not null then t.TopicDate ELSE
   case WHEN PostDate is not null then PostDate ELSE
      VoteDate END END DESC
```

cheers

Comment: I just pasted it without the C at the end. :) Im just not sure how to do it in 1 request to get all the values (i select) from all tables sorted by date (mixed with each other and then putted in order)

Comment: so, do you want to combine the three dates and order by that new combined column, right?
Or do you need to do some sort of union of those three tables and order the results by date?

Comment: yup, thats exactly what i want to do combine and then sort them. Anyway there shouldnt be any duplicates so union might work as well

Comment: OK, I have eddited the question with the combined date. I hope it's useful